# How to combine audio files with PHP?

Tags: php, audio, pear

I want to create a basic speech software, where the PHP program combines a few ready-made sounds (such as `the`, `cat`, `sat`, `on`, `the`, `mat`), and then allows the user to download the finished file (which then, following from the above example, would say `the cat sat on the mat`).

A few options I have considered:

- Some kind of PHP or PEAR library (not PEAR if possible please)
- Reading using a binary-safe reading function from all the audio files, then combining them manually

Are there any I have missed? Or have I not covered the correct option yet?

Comment: PHP can run any executable that the user running the php script has permissions on .. you can look into any command line utility that does this and use PHP as a wrapper.

Comment: not sure about the external app or using PHP to call it?

Comment: The downvote is likely because you've asked a polling question; you asked  the community to provide you with a list of things, which doesn't make for a good Stack Overflow question. See [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) to get an idea on how you could [edit] and improve your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need to do this using native PHP, then you're probably out of luck.

I don't know about your exact need, but the I would second the idea to use a dedicated library, such as [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/), driven by your PHP code through `exec()`.

Also, supposing you are writing a web application, expect the processing time to be long enough that you will have to manage running async sound generation.

Answer (score 0):

Use SoX, it works fine:

```
$ sox read.wav the.wav internet.wav read-the-internet.mp3
```

You might need the `libsox-fmt-all` package to have support for your file types.